# Spring Data JPARepository and @Transactional For Multiple Operations inside One Method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The saveUser method doesn't save the user object name change when I have multiple operations inside one method.  If I use @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) on top of the saveUser service method, it works fine. When another class creates a new User object and sets all its values and calls the createUser method, it works fine.  Why do I need @Transactional for the saveUser method?  In what cases do I need to include @Transactional?  I'm using Spring Data and JPA (Hibernate impl).  Any ideas?

**JPA Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

//getters/setters..etc

}
```

**Spring Service:**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl{
  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  public void saveUser(Long id){
      User user = userRepository.findById(id);
      user.setName("newname");
      userRepository.save(user);
  }

  public void createUser(User user){
      userRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

**Spring Data JPA/Hibernate Impl Repository:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The methods in `JpaRepository` are transactional by default (readonly for retrieving).

Now in your `saveUser()` method, you need `@Transactional` because you are retrieving an `User` by `id` and updating it and then again persisting to the database. Basically, `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` is used while reading else `@Transactional` is used in Spring Data JPA.

```
 User user = userRepository.findById(id);
```

returns `null` to `user` if no user is found and `user.setName("newname");` will give `NullPointerException`.

Comment: "readonly for retrieving" - I think this assumes that the scope of the Persistence Context is itself transactional. Entities would remain attached were the Persistence Context of the EntityManager instance used by the JpaRepository set to be extended.

Comment: Personally I think the code in the question should work without a problem. The save method of JpaRepository uses the entity that is in the P. Context if it exists and, in case it doesn't, it does a select by the Id of the entity to bring it into the context. Then it makes the update, and as the save method is transactional by default, when the transaction finishes the commit is made and the flush in the database. If the saveUser method is annotated with @Transactional, both operations will share the P. Context and it will not be necessary to make the select to bring the entity to the context.

Answer (score 0):

You need transactions if you update the database state (insert/update/delete) otherwise you'll end up having this behaviour.

Even if you do read-only operations in your methods, you should annotate them with `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` so Spring can optimize the transactional resource.